# Can Xcode log console be modified to output the time in local machine timezone instead of GMT?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, logging

Can Xcode log console be modified to get the time output in local timezone but not in **GMT**?

I use the following code:

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setYear:1979];
[comp setMonth:5];
[comp setDay:10];
[comp setHour:10];
[comp setMinute:30];
[comp setSecond:0];
[comp setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                   initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *dateOfBirth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
NSLog(@"\nDate of birth in GMT %@\n\n", dateOfBirth);
```

That produces the following output in the log console:

```
Date of birth in GMT 1979-05-10 08:30:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you evaluate an NSDate in this way it actually calls the `description` method, which returns the date in UTC.  If you wanted to display a date to your user you should use an `NSDateFormatter`, but for simple logging you can use `descriptionWithLocale:` -

```
NSLog(@"\nDate of birth in local time zone %@\n\n", [dateOfBirth descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

Comment: Thanks..that helped...but how can NSLocale init correctly? the following is wrong for sure..
`NSLocale *localTime = [[NSLocale alloc] init]];`

Comment: Which locale are you after `[NSLocale currentLocale]` gives you the current user locale. You can use `initWithLocaleIdentifier` to get a specific locale; e.g. `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-us"]`